# Proving that on a Lie group $G$ with a bi-invariant Riemannian metric, the geodesics through $e$ are precisely the one-parameter subgroups of $G$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

I am trying to prove the following result:

> The geodesics in a Lie group $G$ with a bi-invariant metric $g$ are precisely the one-parameter subgroups of $G$.

To do so, first I proved that if $\nabla$ is the Riemannian connection, then $\nabla_X X =0$ for any left-invariant vector field $X$. Thus, if $\gamma$ is a one-parameter subgroup, then $\gamma$ is a geodesic since $\gamma'$ is a left-invariant vector field.

However, I am finding it difficult to prove the converse. I started with a (maximal) geodesic through $e \in G$. Then, we can extend $\gamma' \left( 0 \right)$ to a left-invariant vector field $X$. I now want to prove that $\gamma$ is the maximal integral curve of $X$ so that it is a one-parameter subgroup. However, I am not sure how to proceed.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Recall that a geodesic is uniquely determined by its initial point and initial direction.

Comment: Ah, yes! I can see the triviality now that you have mentioned it! Thank you for the input!